# Java JFrame not working properly in while loop

Tags: java, swing

When I try to run this, I keep getting an empty frame that cannot be closed, and I have to terminate the program from eclipse. I am fairly certain that the problem is a result of the while loop (about 2/3 of the way down the code block), but I haven't been able to figure out a way to fix this

```
public Draw()
{
    super( "Uno");

    JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar(); // create menu bar
    JMenu gameMenu = new JMenu( "Play Game" );
    JMenu quitMenu = new JMenu( "Quit" ); //Quit Program
    bar.add( gameMenu ); // add Add menu to menu bar
    bar.add( quitMenu ); // add quit button to menu bar
    setJMenuBar( bar ); // set menu bar for this application

    window = new JDesktopPane();
    add(window);

    gameMenu.addMouseListener(
        new MouseListener()
        {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
            {
                Dimension size = window.getSize();
                double height = size.getHeight();
                double width = size.getWidth();
                JInternalFrame frame = new JInternalFrame("Uno", true, true, true, true );


                JFrame input = new JFrame();
                input.setTitle(" ");
                input.setSize(350, 155);
                input.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                input.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                input.setVisible(true);
                JLabel label1 = new JLabel("How many total players? (2-10)");
                final JTextField text1 = new JTextField(3);
                JLabel label2 = new JLabel("How many computer players? *");
                final JTextField text2 = new JTextField(3);
                JLabel label3 = new JLabel("* Computer players must be <= total number of players");
                JButton confirm = new JButton("OK");

                label1.setVisible(true);
                label2.setVisible(true);
                label3.setVisible(true);
                text1.setVisible(true);
                text2.setVisible(true);
                confirm.setVisible(true);

                input.add(label1);
                input.add(text1);
                input.add(label2);
                input.add(text2);
                input.add(label3);
                input.add(confirm);

                while(valid == false)
                {
                    confirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                    {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                        {
                            String players = text1.getText();
                            String computers = text2.getText();
                            int temp1 = Integer.parseInt(players);
                            System.out.println("Number of players = " + temp1);
                            int temp2 = Integer.parseInt(computers);
                            System.out.println("Number of computers = " + temp2);
                            if (temp1 >= 2 && temp1 <= 10)
                                if (temp2 <= temp1 && temp2 >= 0)
                                    valid = true;

                        } //close actionPerformed
                    }); //close ActionListener
                } //close while loop
           } //close mouseClicked
     } //close mouseListener
} //close Draw
```

Initially, I was having an issue where it kept infinitely drawing the frame on top of itself because the while loop kept returning false. That issue was solved by removing the components from the while loop, and placing them before it as they are above. Now when I run it, all I get is this: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRcbM.png)

The goal of this program is to make an Uno game, but the first step is to determine the number of players. This is the only way I know how to do this, and this is only the second program I have done with graphics, so I am by no means an expert at Java. I will appreciate any help I can get because I have been stuck for a few days now.

Comment: When do you expect the value of `valid` to change? (Hint: it's in an event handler that can never be called since you have coopted the CPU for an infinite while loop.)

Comment: I forgot to add the declaration of valid in above. Outside of draw I have it declared `private static boolean valid = false;` Is that what you mean?

Comment: I missed that detail, but it is irrelevant to the real problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not giving the event handlers any chance to do their job. Your while loop continually creates event handlers. However, the `actionPeformed()` method can never be called because the while loop has control of the CPU and the button will not respond to any clicks.

I suggest that you learn a bit more about event handling. You will need to redesign your code in order to get the behavior you wish. Most likely you need to remove the while loop entirely and just create an event handler which will execute code when the button is clicked.

---

*For future reference:*

In general, checking equality with a boolean value is unnecessary. The result of `==` is a bool, but the variable you are checking is already a `bool`. So use it directly: instead of `while (valid == false)`, you can do `while (!valid)`. If you read the `!` as "not", this actually makes a lot of sense.

In this case, the point is moot, since you need to remove the while loop entirely. However, this might be useful information for you some time in the future.